# How to determine if there is a surjective homomorphism from $U(15)$ to $\mathbb{Z}_4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to determine if there is a surjective homomorphism from $U(15)$ to $\mathbb{Z}_4$? $U(15)$ is the multiplicative group of positive integers less than $n$ that are coprime with $n$.

I already know $U(15)$ is not cyclic with 3 elements of order 2, 4 elements of order 4. $U(15)=\{1,2,4,7,8,11,13,14\}$. While $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is obviously cyclic.

Comment: @ Arthur yes,zero homomorphism. I lost the condition 'surjective'.

Comment: You solve this by trying. If there is a surjective homomorhism, then some element has to hit $1\in \Bbb Z_4$. Which elements could do that? Then which elements do you know where they're mapped? Then try the rest of the elements.

Comment: $1\in \mathbb{Z}_4$ is of order 4. hence the elements hit 1 should have order 4 .They should be 2,7,8,13. The rest except 1 should hit $3\in \mathbb{Z}_4$?

Comment: What order does $3\in \Bbb Z_4$ have? If $f(2) = 1$, then what must $f(8) = f(2\cdot 2\cdot 2)$ be? And remember that $2$ and $0$ are in there too.

Answer (score 0):

$f(2)=f(7)=1$

$f(8)=f(13)=3$

Can you finish?

Comment: $f(4)=f(11)=f(14)=2?$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Consider the canonical projection $U(15) \twoheadrightarrow U(5)$ given by $x \bmod 15 \mapsto x \bmod 5$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall **the Chinese remainder theorem**:

> let $A$ be an arbitrary ring, $\Lambda \neq \emptyset$ a finite set (of indices) and $I \in (\mathcal{Id}_b(A))^{\Lambda}$ a family of **pairwise comaximal bilateral (two-sided) ideals** of $A$, which specifically means that $$\lambda, \mu \in \Lambda, \lambda \neq \mu \implies I_{\lambda}+I_{\mu}=A$$ Under these conditions the following **isomorphism of rings** takes place:
>
> $${A}\Big{/}\bigcap_{\lambda \in \Lambda} I_{\lambda} \approx \prod_{\lambda \in \Lambda} (A \big{/}I_{\lambda})$$

As a side-note, $\mathcal{Id}$ stands for ideals and the subscript $b$ for bilateral; for sets $M$ and $J$, $M^J$ denotes the cartesian product $\prod \limits_{j \in J} M$, in other words the set of all families of elements of $M$ indexed by $J$.

Applying the general form of the theorem to the ring of integers, you have the following formulation:

> let $I$ be finite and $m \in \mathbb{Z}^I$ such that $i, j \in I, i \neq j \implies m_i \mathbb{Z}+ m_j\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\mathbb{Z}_{\prod\limits_{i \in I} m_i} \approx \prod\limits_{i \in I}\mathbb{Z}_{m_i}$ as rings.

In the instance you are treating, with prime factor decomposition $15=3\cdot5$ the theorem yields the following isomorphism: $$\mathbb{Z}_{15} \approx \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$$
This yields an **isomorphism between the corresponding groups of units** (invertible elements) of the two rings:
$$\mathrm{U}(\mathbb{Z}_{15})\approx \mathrm{U}(\mathbb{Z}_3)\times \mathrm{U}(\mathbb{Z}_5)$$

However the quotient rings appearing as factors in the direct product on the right-hand side are actually fields and it is easily seen that $(\mathrm{U}(\mathbb{Z}_3), \cdot) \approx (\mathbb{Z}_2, +)$ (cyclic of prime order, so any nontrivial element is a generator) and $(\mathrm{U}(\mathbb{Z}_5), \cdot) \approx (\mathbb{Z}_4, +)$ (where either $\overline{2}$ or $\overline{3}$ are generators, being the only elements of order 4). The operations of the respective groups are appended for clarity. You thus eventually obtain the isomorphism:

$$\mathrm{U}(\mathbb{Z}_{15}) \approx \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$$

exhibiting the invariant factors of $\mathrm{U}(\mathbb{Z}_{15})$ as a finitely generated torsion $\mathbb{Z}$-module (cnf. the theory of finitely generated modules over principal ideal domains). At this point you can easily determine all the subgroups and quotient groups of $\mathrm{U}(\mathbb{Z}_{15})$.

Answer (score 0):

You have got that $U(15)\cong\mathbb Z_4\oplus \mathbb Z_2$.  So the existence of a surjective homomorphism is clear.